Why is my character not recognizing all 3 of my physics objects in my 8th wall game- 'A-frame: Physics Character Controller'
After cloning the game "A-Frame: Physics Character Controller" in 8th wall and adding custom game logic, which included three separate level platforms instead of one, I encountered an issue. The character only recognizes the first platform level, even though I imported all three in the same GLB file. This means that the character walks on top of the first platform and recognizes it as an object, but walks through the other platforms and ignores them, which is creating a problem in the game in the entire game, how do I get the character to recognize all 3 platforms as objects.
I need the character to be able to walk on top of all three 'Physics Objects'not just on one of them.
